# How can I check checkboxes by testing their high and low values with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm having trouble testing and checking a group of checkboxes based on their values. The example below shows some checkboxes where if the value of the checkbox is higher then the one checked, then should be checked. If the value is equal or lower to the one checked, then should not be checked.

I appreciate the help guys!

```
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="5"> One</label>
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="5"> two</label>
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="15"> three</label>
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="25"> four</label>
```

JS

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function (e) {

            var $value = $(this).val();
            var $siblings = $('input[name="' + $(this).attr("name") + '"]').not(":checked");

            $.each($siblings, function (i, input) {

                console.log(input.value)


                if ($value != input.value) {
                    $(this).prop('checked', true);
                }
                else if ($value > input.value) {
                    $(this).prop('checked', true);
                }
                else if ($value >= input.value) {
                    $(this).prop('checked', true);
                }
                else {
                    $(this).prop("checked", false);
                }

            })
        });
```

Comment: what is currently happening??

Comment: So, you want the checkbox with the highest value to be checked?

Comment: `if ($value != input.value)` that's going to return true for at least  2 of the boxes

Comment: Wha happens if it's **unchecked** ??

Comment: Checkbox values are `typeof === 'string'` so you should use [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hdtrp902/14/)

I was having the problem with the value being a string and not being an int so I just used `parseInt` to fix that on both levels.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function (e) {

    var $value = parseInt($(this).val());
    var $siblings = $('input[name="' + $(this).attr("name") + '"]').not(":checked");

    $.each($siblings, function (i, input) {
         var _this = parseInt(input.value);
         if(_this > $value){
             input.checked = true;
         }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

http://jsfiddle.net/6kkchbor/

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function (e) {

    var $value = parseInt($(this).val());
    var $siblings = $('input[name="' + $(this).attr("name") + '"]:checked').not($(this));
    var isCheck = true;

    $siblings.each(function (i) {
        var a = $(this).val() || 0;

        if ($value <= a) {
            isCheck = false;
        }
    });

    $(this).prop("checked", isCheck);
});
```

`$('input[name="' + $(this).attr("name") + '"]:checked').not($(this))` grabs the checked boxes not including what you clicked on.

The `each()` loop simply sets the check flag and then you set the clicked box to check or not depending on the result. This will also allow you to uncheck the clicked box

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function (e) {
    if (!$(this).is(":checked")) return;

    var siblings = $("input[name='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']");
    var value = parseInt($(this).val());
    var elements  = $("input[name='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']:not(:checked)");

    $.each(elements, function (index, element) {
        if (value > parseInt($(element).val())) {
            $(element).prop('checked', true);
        }
        else {
            $(element).prop("checked", false);
        }
    })
});
```

Here is also a JSFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ilgityildirim/6dy76b02/).

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
    var firstCheckboxVal = 0;
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function (e) {

        if(firstCheckboxVal == 0) 
            firstCheckboxVal = $(this).val();
        else {
            if(parseInt($(this).val()) > parseInt(firstCheckboxVal)) 
                $(this).prop('checked', true);
            else
                $(this).prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
```

I am not sure but i think it's work for you.

Answer (score 0):

**JSFIDDLE** https://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/7wcs5sah/

This example will check all checkboxes with value greater than or equal to the value of the checked checkbox when it is checked.
When it is unchecked, all boxes with values greater than it will remain checked, and all boxes with values less than it will be unchecked.

You can use the `.siblings()` function to iterate through all sibling checkbox elements if you have them in the same parent container.

the checkbox values were coming back as strings, so I used `parseInt()` to convert them to numbers before comparing them against eachother.

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function (e) {
        var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
        var checkedValue = $(this).val();
        var siblings = $('input[type=checkbox]');

        siblings.each(function () {
            var siblingValue = parseInt($(this).val());
            //if checked, then check all boxes with values > checkedValue
            //if unchecked, then uncheck all boxes with values <= checkedValue
            $(this).prop('checked', 
                         (checked && (siblingValue >= checkedValue)) || 
                         (!checked && (siblingValue > checkedValue)));
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. Start by finding the value of the highest checked and then uncheck if this value is less or equal to the current checkbox.

Keep in mind that `.val()` returns the value of the first in the collection, hence the sorting.

```js
$(':checkbox[name=a]').on('change', function() {
  var max = +$(':checkbox[name=a]:checked').not(this).sort(function(a,b) {
    return +b.value - +a.value;
  }).val();
  if( +this.value <= max ) {
     this.checked = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="5"> One</label>
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="5"> two</label>
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="15"> three</label>
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="25"> four</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of your jQuery because it's tightly coupled to html. My answer would be to decouple your checkboxes (based on [Philip Walton @ Google - Decoupling your Html, Css and Javascript](http://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/))

HTML

```
<div class="js-checker-group">
<label class="checkbox"
  <input class="js-checker-item" type="checkbox" name="a" value="5">
  One
</label>
<label class="checkbox">
  <input class="js-checker-item" type="checkbox" name="a" value="5">
  two
</label> 
<label class="checkbox">
  <input class="js-checker-item" type="checkbox" name="a" value="15">
  three
</label>
<label class="checkbox">
  <input class="js-checker-item" type="checkbox" name="a" value="25">
  four
</label>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.js-checker-group input[type="checkbox"].js-checker-item')
  .change(function (e) 
{
  var $this = $(this);
  var $group = $this.closest('.js-checker-group');
  var thisValue = parseInt($this.val());
  if ($group.length == 1
     && $this.prop('checked')
     && !isNaN(thisValue)) 
  {
    $group.find('input[type="checkbox"].js-checker-item')
      .each(function()
    {
      var $other = $(this);
      var otherValue = parseInt($other.val());
      if (!isNaN(otherValue) && !$this.is($other))
      {
        var isGreater = otherValue < thisValue;
        $other.prop('checked', isGreater);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I would discourage you write javascript that is dependant on the outcome how you write your html in terms of siblings, parents etc.  One change can result in your javascript not working at all.

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/erikphilips/xt9a2e6b/)